# Given a huge symmetric positive definite matrix, how to calculate a few diagonal elements of its inverse?

Tags: fortran

**Update:** This is a pure **Fortran question now**; [I put the maths stuff on M.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64420/is-there-a-faster-way-to-calculate-a-few-diagonal-elements-of-the-inverse-of-a-hu).

Consider a `P`x`P` symmetric and positive definite matrix `A` (P=70000, i.e. `A` is roughly 40 GB using 8-byte doubles). We want to calculate the first three diagonal elements of the inverse matrix `inv(A)[1,1]`, `inv(A)[2,2]` and `inv(A)[3,3]`.

I have found  [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167947388900928) by James R. Bunch who seems to solve this exact problem without calculating the full inverse `inv(A)`; **unfortunately he uses Fortran and LINPACK, both of which I've never used**.

I'm trying to understand this function:

```
    SUBROUTINE SOLVEJ(A,LDA,P,Y,J)
    INTEGER LDA,P,J
    REAL A(LDA,1),Y(1)
C
    INTEGER K
    Y(J) = 1/A(J,J)
    DO 10 K = J + 1,P
    Y(K) = - SDOT(K - J,A(J,K),1,Y(J),1)/A(K,K)
    10 CONTINUE
    RETURN
    END
```

where `A` is a matrix of size LDA x P and `Y` is a vector of length P.

Can you explain **why he defines `Y(1)` in the function head but then assigns to `Y(J)`?** Does Fortran just not care about the size of the defined array and lets you access beyond its end? Why not define `Y(P)`, which seems possible according to [this Fortran Primer](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~mspieg/mmm/Fortran.pdf)?

Comment: It looks like LAPACK is indeed integrated into MATLAB; see [this press release](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/clevescorner/win00.cleve.html). A lot of basic matrix operations such as `mldivide` `lu`, `qr`, etc, are called from LAPACK.

Comment: Dunno if you found [this list of LAPACK/LINPACK functions](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node147.html), could be helpful in reading that paper. Looks like a lot of this is based on a Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: @strictly: Yes, MATLAB uses LAPACK for a lot of calculations; but my question is about the two functions I cite above and whether *they* are part of LAPACK. I have searched [the docs](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/) but not found them, so I fear the answer in no.

Comment: @strictlyrude27 I hadn't seen that conversion list, thank you. And yes, the paper uses Cholesky decomposition; I actually need to update the question since I missed that `SOLVEJ()` already expects variable A to contain the upper triangular Cholesky decomposition `R` of `A`.

Comment: that question hurts my brain. how about http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @yi_H I was wondering which of the two would be better. Since I felt more unsure about the Fortran side of things and I was looking for information about implementations of this thing, I felt SO to be the better site... but feel free to propose it be transferred!

Comment: you have the paper which explains it, but you're asking us to deduce it from two code blocks?

Comment: @steabert - paper is linked in OP.

Comment: @strictlyrude27: no use if I can't access it...

Comment: @steabert - ah, right. I was on my university campus when I accessed it. I'll download it tomorrow and mirror it.

Comment: @staebert you are right, I need to sort out my mathematics questions from my Fortran questions better. I'm working on an edited question.

Comment: thanks for that, also you put `l` instead of `1` in your example

Comment: @steabert: thanks, those `l` were OCR errors in the original PDF... I had corrected some by hand, but missed a few. Corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should be aware of the different Fortran versions, especially 77 VS 90/95 and beyond, and that indeed you can (normally) go out of bounds just like in C.  Arrays in fortran can cause a lot of confusion, and I would say that it's a bit of a mess.  To limit the discussion to your specific case, we can use the fact that this is about a *dummy array*, which is an array that appears in the dummy argument list of a procedure.  For dummy arrays, we can have 3 types:

1. explicit shape: dimensions are explicitly declared
2. assumed-shape: no dimensions given, only colons to denote the rank of the array
3. assumed-size: last dimension is an asterisk, leading dimensions are explicitly declared

To complicate things, (3) can be grouped with (1), and (2) is usually grouped with deferred-shape arrays, such as e.g. allocatable arrays.  The deferred-shape and assumed-shape is only for Fortran 90/95 and beyond and requires an explicit interface if you want to use them as dummy arguments, so it's typically used in a module.

So, in your case, while `Y(1)` works because you can go out of bounds, it's very bad since the program will fail when you would compile it with `-fcheck=bounds`.  One should write either the valid Fortran 77:

```
REAL A(LDA,*),Y(*)
```

or, much better:

```
REAL A(LDA,P),Y(P)
```

Comment: IIRC the use of 1 for the bounds rather than * is a left-over from Fortran 66, which didn't have *.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've tried to google for "dummy array" and "dummy argument" - do I understand it correctly that in Fortran a "dummy argument" is one where the caller provides memory which is then filled by the called function?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: No, "dummy argument" is the term used when referring to an argument inside a procedure. The actual argument is the actual data that gets associated with the dummy argument on procedure entry. Roughly speaking, see the standard for a proper definition.

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg - Try to think of dummy arguments as "placeholders" for actual data.